# Node.js / MongoDB: can't catch error from Cursor.map callback outside of this callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

mongodb 3.6.3

node 8.10.0

I discovered this accidentally and after some time researching problem still can't figure it out. My code has global error handler that should catch all errors, but error that originated from `find().map` callback was skipped by it and process was exited with standard error log to console.

Here is test code that i come up with

```
(async () => {
  const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

  const uri = 'your uri';

  const connection = MongoClient.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true});
  connection.catch((e) => {
    console.log('inside connection.catch');
    console.log(e);
  });

  const collection = (await connection).db().collection('collection');

  const findPromise = collection.find({}).limit(0).skip(0);

  const functionWithError = (item) => {
    throw new Error('functionWithError');
  };

  // This fails to catch error and exits process
  // try {
  //   const items = await findPromise.map(functionWithError).toArray().catch((e) => console.log('Promise catch 1'));
  //   console.log(items);
  // } catch (e) {
  //   console.log('map error 1');
  //   console.log(e);
  // }

  // This (obviously) works and 'inside map error' is written to console
  try {
    const items = await findPromise.map(() => {
      try {
        functionWithError();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('inside map error'); // this will be outputted
      }
    }).toArray().catch((e) => console.log('Promise catch 2'));
    console.log(items);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('map error 2');
    console.log(e);
  }

})();
```

I don't see any problem in code and expect `'Promise catch 1'` or `'map error 1'` to be logged to console. So whats the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its about the scope of asynchronous function. If you try to use asynchronous function in `try..catch` block, asynchronous function goes out of scope of `try..catch` block, so it, it is always good practice to return errors in asynchronous function callback, which can be handled by simple `if..else` check.

[Useful link](https://bytearcher.com/articles/why-asynchronous-exceptions-are-uncatchable/)

Example1: throwing an error in async-await, where no asynchronous process is running.

```js
(async () => { 
 const someAsync = async () => { 
  throw new Error('error here'); 
 };
 try {
  await someAsync();
 } catch (e) {
  console.log('error cached as expected!');
 }
 console.log('execution continues');
})();
```

Example2: throwing an error in async-await, where the asynchronous process is running.

```js
(async () => { 
 const someAsync = async () => {
    let timeInMS = 0; // 0 milliseconds
  let timer = setTimeout(function() {
   clearTimeout(timer);
   throw new Error('error here'); 
  }, timeInMS);
 };
 try {
  await someAsync();
 } catch (e) {
  console.log('error cached as expected!');
 }
 console.log('execution continues');
})();
```

Comment: But i thought we have `await` operator for such use-cases. See example code below:
    `(async () => {
      const someAsync = async () => {
        throw new Error('error here');
      };

      try {
        await someAsync();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error cached as expected!');
      }

      console.log('execution continues');
    })();`

Console output:
`error cached!`

`execution continues`

Comment: Or do you want to say that even with await in `await findPromise.map` `.map` will be executed asynchronously ?

Comment: I have added examples in my answer, I hope it will help you understand what is really asynchronous function.